# How to verify a restored SVN repository?

Tags: svn

I've restored another SVN server's repository onto a new SVN server. How shall I verify the restored repository? Is the following enough?

1. Run `svnadmin verify` on the repository
2. Check out some major project.
3. Modify and Commit.

Is there anything else I need to test?

Comment: Did my answer help you in 2014? Please, upvote and accept if it helped. :)

Answer (score 0):

- Run [`svnadmin verify`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svnadmin.c.verify.html) to check the repository for corruptions,
- Make sure the [repository hooks](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.reposadmin.create.html#svn.reposadmin.hooks) are working on the new server.

It also makes sense to `svn checkout` the repository and do a commit, but if `svnadmin verify` told you that the repository is consistent (i.e. no errors found) then the repository should be healthy.